Standardized or unstandardized coefficients to report? The covariances and regression of a multivariate latent growth model
I am currently running a second-order latent growth curve with multiple constructs.
This multivariate latent growth curve demonstrates how two (or more) constructs travel
together across time.
My question is, when reporting the regression/covariances among the latent growth factors (e.g. intercept growth factor A and B and slope growth factor C and D) do I report
the standardized coefficients or the unstandardized coefficients?
My guess is that you report the standardized coefficients like you do for the covariance
of the growth factors when running a latent growth curve with one construct.
I wanted to confirm this but I couldn't find resources which clearly stated this.
Thank everyone in advance for your advice!

The covariances between the growth factors tend to be more difficult to interpret than the correlations (standardized coefficients). Nonetheless, for the sake of completeness, reproducibility, and for meta-analytic purposes, my recommendation is to report both unstandardized and standardized coefficients.

Thank you so much for the incite! Also, I am terribly sorry about the late response. As you advised, I will report both standardized and unstandardized coefficients. Thank you always for your help!
